# За счет чего срабатывают категории при изменении крайнего срока задачи в представлении Сроки в Битрикс24

Tags: windows, битрикс24, crm, бизнес-логика

Есть представление Сроки в Битрикс24

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При изменении крайнего срока в задаче меняется временная категория задачи. Например, задача с крайним сроком 29.12.2023 19:00 находилась в категории **На этой неделе**, а при изменении крайнего срока на 01.01.2024 значение категории становится равным **На следующей неделе**. За счет чего это происходит? Я смотрел роботов для данного представления, но ничего не обнаружил.